# Do we have any api's or web services avialable for monster or naukri to integrate in asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone please help me out suggesting any documentations/blogs available for the above subject.

Answer (score 0):

Ershad,

**If you are looking for the resume search in Naukri & Monster, then NO.**

They are paid service providers.  You will get access to their system once you become a paid subscriber.  I am not sure whether they exposed any web service apis for this.

Comment: Not about resume search,About normal search results for anonymus user in the site

Comment: can able to list those paid providers

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something with their RSS feed, by playing around with the search options you can see how they are represented in the querystring, and pull apart the returned XML...

Comment: Are you talking about screen scraping.

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about making a call to the RSS handler, consuming the returned XML, and parsing that - as RSS is a validatable XML format, in a structured format, this would be easier than direct screen scaping, but would still miss important and useful bits of data. A quick look at their site didn't find any other sort of exposed API for searching jobs - they want you to search directly on their site, not on some 3rd party site with its own ads, etc.